# lightning-input type="datetime" does not hold the time value at first time in the UI

Tags: lightning-web-components, datetime, lightninginput

When I select the time first in the date time field it does not hold the value and when I do the same again and select the time first it holds it. Below is my code :

JS :

```
@api endDateTime = null;
handleEndChange (event) {
    this.endDateTime = event.detail.value;       
}
```

html :

```
<lightning-input class="" type="datetime" name="End" label="End" value={endDateTime} onchange={handleEndChange} message-when-value-missing=" " message-when-bad-input=" " required></lightning-input>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please edit the question adding how `endDateTime` is initialized?

Comment: @api endDateTime;

Answer (score 0):

Once a variabile has been declared without initializing it (i.e. `@api endDateTime;`), it's `undefined`.

When you set only the time part, the handler runs, but `event.detail.value` holds `null` (it's a datetime field, just the time part is not enough to have a valid value), therefore `endDateTime` is overwritten.
Please note that `null` and `undefined` are different values with different meanings (`null !== undefined`) and a variable used in the template is [reactive](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reactivity-fields.html), therefore the framework reacts to that change refreshing the `lightning-input` component passing `null` as value, which remove your value.
That's why the first time it seems that the component does't hold the value.

After that, if you set again just the time, `endDateTime` keeps `null` as value, so it doesn't change and the framework doesn't refresh the `lightning-input`, therefore, starting from the second time, the component *works*, it hold the time value.

To fix it, just initialize the variable to `null`:

```js
@api endDateTime = null;
```

Please note that you should use [`@api`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reactivity-public.html) decorator only if want to make `endDateTime` public, i.e. if you want to set it via lightning builder or from a parent component.

Comment: This is not the issue. I tried this but still the at the first time it does not show the time selected on UI

Comment: Please check if `Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance` is enabled from Setup > Session Settings. If so, please disable it, then refresh the page and retry.

Comment: Not working .. tried this